# my code seems perfect but showing wrong output. can someone help me what wrong am i doing here?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, hash, hashmap

i have to return the max len of consecutive seq present in an array.
consider the example:-

```
N = 7
a[] = {2,6,1,9,4,5,3}
```

my code should return 6 but its giving 1. don't know how?

```
int findLongestConseqSubseq(int arr[], int N)

 {
    //Your code here
    unordered_map<int,int> mp;
    int ans=0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(mp.count(arr[i])>0){
            continue;
        }
       int len1=mp[arr[i]-1];
       int len2=mp[arr[i]+1];
       int ns=len1+len2+1;
       ans=max(ans,ns);
       mp[arr[i]-len1]=ns;
       mp[arr[i]+len2]=ns;
      // ans=max(ans,ns);
       }
     return ans;
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain why your code should return the correct result? Its not that obvious. I also dont understand why the correct result for your example input should be 6

Comment: It took me a moment to understand this question - it is asking to get the largest number of consecutive digits in a scrambled array and return it. For example, if my array had the numbers [9,0,1,2,3,6,8] then that would be [0,1,2,3] or 4 consecutive numbers.

Comment: I think it would help if you sorted the array first with something like the c++ sort() function https://www.cplusplus.com/articles/NhA0RXSz/ and then checked for the longest streak of running numbers once it is sorted.

Comment: Code without an indication what it is to accomplish, but misspellings in identifiers does not seem perfect. What *is* `LongestConseq[uent?!]Subseq[uence]`/a `consecutive seq[uence]`?

Comment: no need for sorting in this approach we have to do it in O(N). and approach is the correct only problem is with the map thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your implementation.

The first issue is the code:

```cpp
        if(mp.count(arr[i])>0){
            continue;
        }
```

this code is not sufficient to ensure that repeated numbers do not make it into the rest of your loop (to see why this is, consider what happens with neither `len1` or `len2` are zero).

You can replace it with something like:

```cpp
        if(!mp.insert(pair<int,int>(arr[i], 1)).second) {
            continue;
        }
```

This will skip the rest of the loop if an entry for `arr[i]` exists, but also ensures that an entry will exist after the if expression is evaluated.

The second issue is with the code:

```cpp
       int len1=mp[arr[i]-1];
       int len2=mp[arr[i]+1];
```

the subscript operator for maps in C++ has a side-effect of creating an entry if one does not exist. This is problematic for your algorithm because you do not want this to happen. If it did it would cause the previous piece of code to skip numbers it shouldn't. The solution is to use `find` but since the code for this is a little ugly (IMHO) it's probably neater to write a helper function:

```cpp
inline int findOrDefault(const unordered_map<int, int>& map, int key, int defaultValue) {
    auto find = map.find(key);
    return (find == map.end()) ? defaultValue : find->second;
}
```

and use this to update your code to:

```cpp
        int len1=findOrDefault(mp, arr[i]-1, 0);
        int len2=findOrDefault(mp, arr[i]+1, 0);
```

Putting this all together you end up with:

```cpp
inline int findOrDefault(const unordered_map<int, int>& map, int key, int defaultValue) {
    auto find = map.find(key);
    return (find == map.end()) ? defaultValue : find->second;
}

int findLongestConseqSubseq(int arr[], int N)
{
    unordered_map<int,int> mp;
    int ans=0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(!mp.insert(pair<int,int>(arr[i], 1)).second) {
            continue;
        }
        int len1=findOrDefault(mp, arr[i]-1, 0);
        int len2=findOrDefault(mp, arr[i]+1, 0);
        int ns=len1+len2+1;
        ans=max(ans,ns);
        mp[arr[i]-len1]=ns;
        mp[arr[i]+len2]=ns;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much brother it worked and I learned a new thing also. thank you so much @idz

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer! It stops others wasting time reading your question only to realized it is already answered.

Answer (score 0):

Ok had a moment to look at this again and I came up with this. First we sort the array to make things easier. Then we can go through the numbers with one pass, counting each time the next consecutive number is greater by one. If the next number is not one greater after sorting, then we reset and start counting again, storing the highest streak count in max.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;


int main()
{


    cout << "Get Longest Consecutive Streak: " << endl;

    

    int intArray[] = { 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ,16 };

    int arrayLength = size(intArray);    

    sort(intArray, intArray + arrayLength); //Sort Array passing in array twice plus amount of indexes in array

    cout << "Sorted Array looks like this:" << endl; //Outputting sorted array to check
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        cout << intArray[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;


    int count = 1;
    int max = 1;

    /*
    * Loop through array, if the next number is one greater than current then add to count
    * If it is not, reset the count.
    * Store highest count value found passing through.
    * */

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength -1; i++) { 
        if (intArray[i + 1] == intArray[i] + 1) { //checking next value - is it equal to this one + 1?
            count++;
        }
        else { //else if it is not, store the value if it is higher that what is currently there, then reset
            if (max < count) {
                max = count;
            }
            count = 1;
        }
        
    }

    //Edge case: check again one more time if the current count (when finishing) is greater than any previous
    if (max < count) {
        max = count;
    }


    cout << "Longest Consecutive Streak:" << endl;
    cout << max << endl;

    

    return 0;



}
```

Comment: This is a completely different algorithm and is O(n log n) whereas the one the OP posted, when implemented correctly, is O(n).

Comment: it would be O(nlogn) and no need of sorting in this approach.